# React Native HOC component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am trying to do a withCache HoC component but having some problems...

Thats the HoC:

```
// HOC for cached images
const withCache = (Component) => {
  const Wrapped = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const [uri, setUri] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const { uri } = props;

        const name = shorthash.unique(uri);
        const path = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${name}`;
        const image = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path);

        if (image.exists) {
          console.log("Read image from cache");
          setUri(image.uri);
          return;
        } else {
          console.log("Downloading image to cache");
          const newImage = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri, path);
          setUri(newImage.uri);
        }
      })();
    }, []);

    return <Component {...props} uri={uri} />;
  };

  Wrapped.propTypes = Component.propTypes;

  return Wrapped;
};

export default withCache;
```

The thing is that "Component" is a custom Image component with specific propTypes and defaultProps.

How do I use this component? I have tried:

```
const CachedImage = withCache(<MyCustomImage uri={"https://..."} height={100} ripple />)

...

return (<CachedImage />)
```

but not working :( What I want is to pass a boolean prop to my custom image component named "cached", and if true return the custom image component wrapped in the HOC

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the HOC, you would create the instance outside of the functional component like

```
const CachedImage = withCache(MyCustomImage)
```

and use it like

```
const MyComp = () => {
   ...
   return (<CachedImage  uri={"https://..."} height={100} ripple />)
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but seems like if I enter an infinite loop. Do you see something bad in my code? I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: have you made sure `const CachedImage = withCache(MyCustomImage)` is created outside of your component. Also please check if the component which you render cachedImage is causing in infinite loop or your hoc. I can't see anything in HOC that causes an infinite loop if used correctly

Comment: Yeah, outside the component. And this is not because of the logic, I transformed an old component with the same logic that works fine into this HoC.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything that could cause an infinite loop in your HOC

Comment: I found the problem. As in the HoC uri is a state, I need to check if the uri is not null (when it is already read from cache) before rendering my custom image component, bacause uri is a required prop. 
I thought it was an infinite loop because when navigating from one screen to another, the app froze in the middle of navigation, due to the logic that I have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Final implementation of the HoC, in case someone finds it useful in the future.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import shorthash from "shorthash";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

// HOC for cached images
const withCache = (Component) => {
  const Wrapped = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const [uri, setUri] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const { uri } = props;

        const name = shorthash.unique(uri);
        const path = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}${name}`;
        const image = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path);

        if (image.exists) {
          console.log("Read image from cache");
          setUri(image.uri);
          return;
        } else {
          console.log("Downloading image to cache");
          const newImage = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri, path);
          setUri(newImage.uri);
        }
      })();
    }, []);

    // Needs to have the final uri before render the image
    return uri && <Component {...props} uri={uri} />;
  };

  Wrapped.propTypes = Component.propTypes;

  return Wrapped;
};

export default withCache;
```